# Maven : Remove duplicate jars from EAR

Tags: maven, war, ear

We are using maven to build an EAR that contains WAR, the JARS are duplicated on both EAR's root and WAR's lib folder, I read about the skinny jars to remove the jars from the WAR but I don't want this as I want to keep the WAR as stand alone unit,
IS there a way to do it the other way around and remove the JARs from the EAR's root folder ?
attached is the EAR POM

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.csv.xyz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.csv.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Is there any special reason for this? Is it causing you any trouble?

Comment: The only reason, that I want to keep the WAR standalone entity , and able to deploy it anytime

Answer (score 2):

The "**maven-skinny-war**" solution isn't any drawback in your case. Also have a look at this question and my answer: [How to make maven place all jars common to wars inside the same EAR to EAR root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848947/how-to-make-maven-place-all-jars-common-to-wars-inside-the-same-ear-to-ear-root/15230037#15230037)

With this solution you will first get WARs packaged with their own dependencies and second, an EAR module with skinny WARs. So everything is deployable on its own and nothing is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be a good idea because of the class loader architecture. If a JAR is part of a WAR, it's defined by the web app class loader, which may result in multiple instances. If it's part of an EAR, it's defined by the enterprise app class loader, which is a different class loader.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a dependency from the EAR lib folder, declare the dependencies as provided in the EAR pom, for example to remove commons-lang:

```
<dependencies>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```

Just make sure if you have EJB modules that they don't require the dependency! Also webModules do not contribute to the EAR's root lib folder, do you have more dependencies in you ear pom?

Comment: I don't have EJB, also don't have any other dependencies other than the web module as specified on the above POM !

Comment: what is the output of mvn dependency:tree?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is the default behavior if you are not using skinny wars.  When building a multi-module project, the dependencies and transitive dependencies of the WAR is not added to the EAR dependencies list.  This is because by default the WAR dependencies are added to the WEB-INF/lib folder in the WAR.