# How to avoid duplication of derived dependencies in EAR/WAR with Maven?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

To make the example as simple as possible, let's say I have classic Java EE 5 application.
Let's say I use `x-lib` in EAR module, and `x-lib` uses `commons-io`.
Also I use `y-lib` in WAR module, and `y-lib` uses `commons-io` too.
The EAR is set as *provided* in WAR.

The result I get is:

```
- app.ear
    /lib
       x-lib.jar
       commons-io.jar
    /app.war
       /WEB-INF
          /lib
             y-lib.jar
             commons-io.jar
```

I don't want commons-io to be packaged in `app.war/WEB-INF/lib` once it is packaged already in `app.ear/lib`.

In my war's pom.xml I have:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>app</artifactId>
   <type>ejb</artifact>
   <scope>provided</scope>  
   <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>some.other.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>y-lib</artifactId> <!-- This loads commons-io as compile dependency -->
   <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to tell maven that I want everything that is provided along with app ejb dependency should be set to provided and not included in WAR?

**I do not want to track all those duplicated JARs and set them as provided or exclude explicitly one by one.**

*EDIT*

I am aware of skinny-war solution. However I don't like the drwaback of duplicating dependencies in WAR and EAR. Maybe you know how to overcome this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make maven place all jars common to wars inside the same EAR to EAR root?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848947/how-to-make-maven-place-all-jars-common-to-wars-inside-the-same-ear-to-ear-root)

Answer (score 1):

From the version 2.7 of the `maven-ear-plugin`, you can use SkinnyWars.
See here for specs:  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html

Basically, you can add the `skinnyWars` tag to your plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sounds like an option. Tkanks. Already migrated to Spring Boot with embedded container and have one jar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an exclusion like this:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>some.other.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>y-lib</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well I know I can exclude jar like this. But in real world the list of duplicated jars is very long. I don't want every developer to track down all duplicated dependencies once he or she adds or removes a dependency. This is what I wanted Maven to do for me. I wanted Maven to think: "Hey, I don't need to add commons-io along with y-lib because it is already provided with ejb".

Comment: Let me put it this way: Maven isn't psychic.

Comment: Clearly, you have to define what you'd like it to do and what not to do.

An alternative would be to define your preferred version of commons-io in the project which will be packaging this. That usually works as well as means of overriding.

Comment: Well, I don't want it to by psychic. I just wanted to "mark" the dependency to take precedence over others. To force that **provided** is more important than **compile**.

Comment: Yeah, you can also use provided scopes in your modules, but that will leave you in a state where you assembly needs to package that particular dependency, or you environment/container must have the respective dependency on it's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

That SHOULD be automatic if you add the EJB module as a provided dependency to your war module and let all the dependencies of that EJB come transitively. So don't add the overlapping dependencies to your war pom, just let Maven deal with it.

Comment: I am not adding overlaping dependencies explicitly. For example. My EJB is using commons-lang. This is a provided dependency so far. But once I add tomahawk to my WAR commons-lang becomes a compile dependency as a transitive compile dependency from tomahawk. The same happens with lots of libraries and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell maven that I want everything that is provided
>   along with app ejb dependency should be set to provided and not
>   included in WAR?

In this case a think the best option by now is to use [wilcards in dependency exclusion](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3832).
It is only supported in maven 3.

Below is an example of how to declare the ejbmodule dependency from a war project:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ejbModuleGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejbModuleArtifactId</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>                
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

You can use this same strategy when declaring a dependency to a ejb-client.

Depending on your maven 3 version, you'll get a [nasty warning](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5537), but in newer versions it must be fine.

Comment: But I still want to have this in classpath on compile time. I just don'r want to have it inside the WAR lib.

Comment: If your war uses the dependency directly, then it's a good practice to really declare it in the pom (as provided in this case).