# Skinny WAR, libraries in EAR: "struts-tags not found" error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, war, ear

In a Java EE project, I moved all the libraries from the `WAR/WEB-INF/lib` to the `EAR/lib`.

Opening a JSP, now I get this error:

> Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
>   
> Messages:
>   
> **File "/struts-tags" not found**
>   
> File:    org/apache/jasper/compiler/DefaultErrorHandler.java
>   
> Line number:     51
>
> ```
> Stacktraces
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/struts-tags" not found
> ...........
> ...........
> ```

How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving the libraries from the WAR to the EAR may be very useful, e.g. if you have more than one WAR* inside one EAR, to avoid redundancy of libraries.

<sub>* Note: With multiple WAR in Struts2, you *may* encounter problems in some application server: [read more on the official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/multiple-struts-2-wars-in-a-single-ear.html).</sub>

To make a [Skinny WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html) (a WAR without libraries) work, the conditions are:

1. The WAR's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` must contain a Class-Path property linking your libraries:

   ```
   Class-Path: lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.2.jar 
               lib/xwork-core-2.3.15.2.jar     
               lib/all_your_libraries_here...
   ```
2. The EAR's `application.xml` must contain:

   `<library-directory>lib</library-directory>`.

To achieve this conditions on Maven, without the need of declaring the dependency of each library of WAR's POM.xml in EAR's POM.xml, you can use [this amazing trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230037/1654265).

That said, the problem reported in the question is given by the fact that the `TLD` lookup is performed on the WAR only, the EAR is out of scope
<sub>(AFAIK, there is no way to lookup a TLD in the EAR, but I'd like to be proven wrong)</sub>.

The solution:

**extract the `struts-tags.tld` from `struts2-core-2.3.x.x.jar`, and place it under** (each) `WAR/WEB-INF` **folder.** <sub>This is related to any kind of TLD file inside a JAR, not only to Struts2.</sub>

In JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld" %>
```

Comment: yep this was what i was thinking of doing too.