# What is the right way to package Struts2 jar files?

Tags: struts2

We encountered the problem while upgrading to Struts2 from Struts1
Our application has .ear with .war file inside. Plus we have another separate .war file.
We were able to upgrade and deploy .ear file with Struts2. 
Hovewer when we tried to deploy second .war file we get the error:

Unable to load configuration. - bean - app-config.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar/struts-default.xml:29:72 ...
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean

Both war files have required struts2 .jar files. 
Then we tried to pull Struts2 .jar files out of .war to JBoss lib directory. JBoss AS run fine but first call to jsp page threw error:

Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/struts-tags" not found

We also tried to create shared .war file that contained only struts2 jar files. We get the same error:

Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/struts-tags" not found

Each .ear and .war files run fine when they deployed alone without each other.
Please advice what is the right way to package Struts2 jar files when application has .war and .ear files.
Thank you,
Yuri

Comment: One workaround I found is to pull struts-tags.tld file out of struts2-core*.jar and drop it to WEB-INF\lib to each .war file.

Comment: Exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19380836/1654265