# Glassfish Classloading

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have one enterprise application with multiple `Web apps`. I'm working on upgrading these apps one by one (mainly the UI part), and in the process I have to use different lib versions.

**What is the best way to do that?**

Does placing the needed libs in `WEBINF/lib` will solve the issue, or do I have to upgrade all the apps at once.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Placing those libs under WEB-INF/lib should solve the issue as long as they don't appear in other places. 
You may want to look at [how to deal with shared-libraries for many web applications using the same libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841117/how-to-deal-with-shared-libraries-for-many-web-applications-using-the-same-libra)

When you mean "upgrading these apps" I assume you want to move to latest version of the library unless there is a platform/framework issue.

In general moving to same version of the library (where-ever possible) for the application and then upgrading all libraries one by one will help.

Comment: thx for ur answer. I have a couple of apps that uses an old jsf framework. I'm working on moving them one by one to the latest version. Problem I have now is liferay deployed on glassfish and uses an old version of some libs, I can't figure a way to skip liferay check for one application.

Comment: If you can provide deployment structure of two conflicting application we can check possibility of skipping of specific jar for single application