# where to put struts-core2.x.x.jar? (in WEB-INF/lib or jboss shared lib)

Tags: java, struts2, struts, struts-tags

where to put struts-core2.x.x.jar? (in WEB-INF/lib or jboss shared lib)

When I'm trying to use struts tag in jsp, I'm getting an error as /struts-tag can not be located.

I've kept all the jars in jboss shared lib folder. In my project configuration, I'm not allowed to put the jars in WEB-INF/lib location.

What should I do?

Comment: Why on earth aren't you allowed to put your web app jars in your own web app? Besides that not every library is implemented well enough to share between webapps, it also means you cannot (trivially) have multiple versions of the same jars deployed at the same time.

Comment: @DaveNewton - We have multiple applications shared on the same server, so I think it is better to keep all the resources (jars) in the shared lib folder.

Comment: That's almost never true, and means you must update everything at once. The things I listed as reasons not to do this aren't imaginary. But good luck anyway!

Comment: @DaveNewton What's *never true*? There's no reasons to do it or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same problem you encounter [creating skinny WARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19380836/1654265) (and then putting the libraries elsewhere, in my case in the EAR).

The [solution I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19380932/1654265) was to:

1. extract TLDs from JARs,
2. put a copy on WEB-INF/lib
3. reference them in the page like this:

   ```jsp
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld" %>
   ```

Comment: I tried this in first place, but I was getting some error. I'll try this once again and will get back to you. Thanks.