# Error Deploying EAR with Spring Security in the War

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I'm trying to pack some ejb (jars) and a war in a ear to deploy in my glassfish server. But, my web application uses struts2 and spring security and when I deploy the ear I get this exception:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The classes from the spring-security-web jar (or one of its dependencies) are not available. You need these to use <http>
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean
```

When I deploy the war I don't get this exception. What I'm doing wrong ?

I'm not using Maven

Comment: Do you the spring security jar only in `WEB-INF\lib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: `org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean`

The message is clearly stating your are missing the [`GenericFilterBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html) class.

This class is located inside `spring-web-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar`.

[Download (the right version of) that JAR](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web) and include it in your EAR to fix the problem.

Comment: And how do you explain that the .war deployment works just fine?

Comment: 1. When deploying the EAR, where are the libraries, in the EAR or in the WAR ? 2. Do you have spring-web-...jar file somewhere ?

Comment: @andrea hi, I'm importing spring-web jar and other spring security dependencies in the war and I can deploy the war but the problem occurs when I pack the war in an ear

Comment: Sounds like a classloading isolation problem. Are *all* of your libraries inside the WAR, when packaged in an EAR ? I guess not... it's possible that you have some libraries in the ear that are not able to load the libraries in the WAR on which they depends because not visible (those libraries are handled by a different classloader). Remember that WAR sees EAR libraries, but EAR does not see WAR's libraries

Comment: Yep the jars for spring security and struts2 are in the /lib at the root of the ear.

Comment: Then try putting all the libraries in the EAR, keeping a [skinny WAR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19380932/1654265), and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue because spring web jar was inside war and other spring security jars were in the ear and as mentioned by Andrei Ligios,  EAR does not see WAR's. I moved spring web war to ear and it worked.

Spring 4.1.6, Spring security 4.0.1

-Rakesh Prajapati