# shared common library for multiple war files using netbeans ad wildfly server

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, wildfly

i am using net beans IDE and wild-fly server.I have multiple war and they share common library. i want to package all the libraries in one place so that they don't appear twice in same ear.

Comment: How are you building this project? Do you use Maven or something similar?

Comment: Yes @steve C but i am using Ant and not maven. i tried to add all the libraries in ear > propertie> library> Mylib> all lib jar. and then in manifest.mf file of war Class pat : lib/Mylib/xyz.jar and in application.xmp <lib-directory> lib </lib-directory> and its not working ...can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JBoss Module for your jars. (under $JBOSSHOME/modules/org/module/for/dependencies/main) You need to copy the jars into the main folder and create a module.xml like that:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.module.for.dependecies">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="xy.jar"/>
    .
    .
    .
  </resources>
</module>
```

Then add to your project(s) a deployment-structure.xml (WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the WAR or META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the EAR). And configure like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
   <dependencies>
     <module name="org.module.for.dependecies"/>
   </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i was thinking to add all the libraries under root ear folder using properties > library > add jar or library. Is it a  good method? can you help me proceed this way?

Comment: How does your project structure look like? Do you have an ear and in ear many wars?

Comment: Yes @awagenoffer i t has an ear and many wars inside ear.although i was trying for 2 war files first.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230037/6418009) answer. It could be the solution.

Comment: @awagwnhoffer the solution was using maven. i am using ant.